# Can you use react-core without react-dom

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

So i've been reading the Facebook docs on `React`. There's a lot of it so I may of missed some however, I read that they're splitting React into `react-core` and `react-dom`.

I found this react-core repo: https://github.com/petehunt/react-core

I was wondering, has the split been made now? As in could I use `react-core` and implement another `virtual-dom` type library in place of `react-dom`?

Comment: Yes.  0.14 is out: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html

Comment: The split was made recently (as of v0.14) because you can use React with no DOM at all and projects utilizing just the core without the need for DOM started to pop out (for example react-art / react-canvas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this split has happened as of React 0.14. The two official packages are [`react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react) and [`react-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom), though they both still live in the [facebook/react repository](https://github.com/facebook/react); the DOM specific stuff is currently [in `ReactDOM.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/ReactDOM.js) while the shared stuff is [exported from `ReactIsomorphic.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/ReactIsomorphic.js). (This is internal, and when using the npm packages, you should just `require("react")` and `require("react-dom")`.)

There are already projects taking advantage of this split; take, for example, [react-blessed](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/react-blessed), a custom renderer for the blessed library:

[image: React Blessed Demo]